# How many actors a Multiplayer game Use Case Diagram has?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am creating a small Multiplayer game. It can only be played when there are two players present (not more than that). 
In a typical single player game, there should be an Actor called "Player". But in this case there are two players. So is it possible to declare "Player1" and "Player2" as actors?

note: In some of the tasks, either one of them will participate. How can I represent that? (just like entering the high-score [only one of them can be the winner. Both of them cannot be the winner at the same time] ).

Is this correct ?? - [image: Use case 2 players]

Comment: Apart from the above question I asked , there is a use case called "Play the game".  If I extend that to another use case called "Play again", Is it allowable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a single actor called `Player` and add a constraint that there need to be exactly 2 player instances. The use cases where the number of players is irrelevant you don't have that constraint.

[image]

`Play again` is no use case. It's probably a simple action in the `Play game` UC where the question pops up.

P.S. You should read Bittner/Spence to get the idea about UC synthesis.

P.P.S.: As already mentioned in the comments, an actor is not a person, but the way some (usually) person acts. If you have a two player game and both players are equal, you have just one actor (the way they act is the same). If you have a game with two different players like one challenger and one opponent, you would use two different actors. Namely `Challenger` and `Opponent`. They both might act similarly when it comes to watching statistics or the like. Now you have a third role `Player` from which the actors above can inherit:

[image]

Comment: I have uploaded a picture to this question (Please look into it). So is that possible to generalise player 1 and player 2 to a "player"?

Comment: if an actor is not related to a usecase it should not be in your UC diagram same for usecases

Comment: Yes, possible. But superfluous. You are trying to show instances with generalization. Use generalization only if you have a different general role like User <- Admin where the admin also has the role of a user and has different UCs than just a user. (What @RedBeard said)

Comment: @Senura You might have something like 'Admin' and 'User' generalized to 'Player'. Admin being the only one of two who can be an actor in scenarios like additional cases like 'See statistic' and 'change settings'.

Answer (score 1):

An UseCase diagram must list the possible kind of usage of your system (the Multiplyer game), the possible kind of actor and their relationship (which usecase is accessible by which kind of actor). So in the case of your game does two players are two different kind of actor (which means that they will not have the same kind of interaction with the game) or are they the same kind of actor (with the same kind of intarction with the game)?

Comment: Player1 and Player2 has no differentiates at all. The winner will be able to access to the "high score".  So at the end one player will access the "High score" and the other player remain as it is.

Comment: No difference so no two kind of actor.... 
For your other reflexion the questions are still the same. Does 'enter a high score' is a use case of my system? if yes put it on your diagram. Which kind of actor will have access to it? The existing Player (in this case add awinning constraint) or another kind of user (winner)? etc.